# Slow to connect to printers shared on Windows Server 2012

Tags: printing, printer, windows-server-2012, network-printer, smb

We have a Windows Server 2012 R2 server setup to share multiple printers on our domain.

Connecting to the first printer on the server during a session takes roughly 45 seconds for the print dialog box to appear and start searching for the driver. After the dialog box finally appears, the remaining driver installation/setup is quite fast.

After the first printer from the server is connected successfully, attempting to connect to a second printer on the server, the print dialog box appears immediately, so it appears something is being cached on the client/server the second time. If the print spooler is restarted on the client machine, we again see a 45 second wait time for the print dialog to appear (tested on Win7/Win10 clients).

We have another print server, also running Server 2012 R2, which doesn't display this behaviour - the only noticable difference is in the event logs for SMBClient.

**The SMBClient log within Event Viewer on the problematic server displays constant errors with event ID 30803:
The network connection failed.
Error: The transport connection attempt was refused by the remote system.
Server name: workstation.ad.domain.com
Server address: 10.100.4.149:445
Connection type: Wsk**

**Guidance:
This indicates a problem with the underlying network or transport, such as with TCP/IP, and not with SMB. A firewall that blocks port 445 or 5445 can also cause this issue.**

Is this error message likely related to the problem? What else could be causing this initial delay to connect to the first printer?

Comment: You've got a lot of things to try (either that or you need to tell us what you've already tried).  Questions: 1) Physical or VM? 2) Machine model? 3) Updated NIC drivers? On clients? 4) Tried different network switch? 5) Change network cabling? 6) Are devices negotiating at the correct network speed? 7) Any errors being detected by your managed switches? 8) Disabled antivirus?

Comment: Ever figure this out?  I see the same thing.  Ever try disabling (WS2008 introduced) Client-Side Rendering?

Answer (score 0):

Spoolsv (print spooler service) on the server listens on a high dynamic port (49152-65535) ("RpcTcp").  Blocking those could cause the delay. The client will try the high port for a while and then go to port 135 (epmap).  This doesn't seem to be documented online at this time.